# Main.xml Error About Library

Tags: android, android-library

I'm trying use Navigation Drawer. Everything is okay, but there is an error here:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_example"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_example"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
</menu>
```

Red underlined (two)line is:

> android:showAsAction="ifRoom"

Information message is [here](http://i.hizliresim.com/YvdMQl.png)

And This line is grayed.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

**Any help can be help!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

to

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

And Clean Build your Project.You are done.Hope it will help.Thanks